# SuperCSV with Dozer - How to map to a List of Lists?

Tags: csv, dozer, supercsv

Using SuperCSV with Dozer (version 2.2.0), I've been able to successfully map data into a `List`. However, I now have a case where I want to map into a `List` of `List`s. In the object I'm trying to map to, I have a field that looks something like this:

```
List<List<String>> myListOfLists;
```

For my field mapping I did this:

"myListOfLists[0][0]", "myListOfLists[0][1]", "myListOfLists[1][0]", etc.

However, this results in the following error:

> org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field
>   (myListOfLists[0]) in class (class
>   com.foo.MyClassBeingMappedTo)

I can't seem to find any examples of nested collections, but it seems like this should be possible. Is there a way I can map the data into my `List<List<String>>` field?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of Dozer - I don't think it can handle nested Lists. You'd think you could use `myListOfLists[0].[0]` but it seems to ignore the trailing `.[0]` altogether, resulting in a `ClassCastException` when you access your List (as it's actually a String!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by creating a wrapper class for my inner `List`. I created an inner class like this:

```
public static class InnerListWrapper
{
    private List<String> innerList;

    public List<String> getInnerList()
    {
        return innerList;
    }
    public void setInnerList(List<String> innerList)
    {
        this.innerList = innerList;
    }
}
```

Then my outer `List` looks like this:

```
List<InnerListWrapper> myListOfLists;
```

Then the fields mapping is simply "myListOfLists[0].innerList[0]","myListOfLists[0].innerList[1]", ""myListOfLists[1].innerList[0]", etc.

Not the cleanest, but like the comment above says, Dozer doesn't seem to support nested Lists. So you have to add another class in between.